# calling enum State to change correctly but it is not changing c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

quick introduction to my project. I am trying to make a game in unity game engine and I am working on its shop system. Everything about the shop system is complete but one problem is still there. I need to save the State of button that is (MyButton) in my game scene and change it with (BuyButton) or (EquipButton) the saving part works but setting the button doesn't, I am using enum and switch statements for that part. These are the scripts of those two things.

script with the enum:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.IO;
 
 public class SaveEverything : MonoBehaviour
 {
     // What script to save
     public LoadEveryThing MyButton;
     
 
     public void Save()
     {
         // What data to save
         string saveData = MyButton.state.ToString();
        
 
         // Where the data is stored
         string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "\\buttonstate.save";
 
         
          // Writes data to file
          if (File.Exists(path))
          {
             File.WriteAllText(path, saveData/*, saveData1, saveData2, saveData3, 5*/);
          }
          else
          {
             File.Create(path).Close();
             File.WriteAllText(path, saveData/*, saveData1, saveData2, saveData3, 5*/);
          }
    }   
 }
 
 public enum  ButtonState
 {
     Buy,
     Equip
 }
```

At the last part of script the enum is declared, with Buy and Equip inside it and rest of the script is about saving MyButton in a string.

Script with the switch statement:

```
using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.IO;
 using System;
 using TMPro;
 
 public class LoadEveryThing : MonoBehaviour
 {
     // Types of buttons
     public GameObject BuyButton;
    /* public GameObject BuyButton1;
     public GameObject BuyButton2;
     public GameObject BuyButton3;*/
    public GameObject EquipButton;
    /*public GameObject EquipButton1;
     public GameObject EquipButton2;
     public GameObject EquipButton3;*/
 
     public ButtonState state;
 
      void Start()
     {
         // What file to read save data from
         string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "\\buttonstate.save";
 
         // Get data and set state to that data
         if (File.Exists(path))
         {
             string data = File.ReadAllText(path);
             
             if (Enum.TryParse(data, out ButtonState State))
                 state = State;
         }
 
         // Copy button properties onto this button
         // depending on the state
         switch (state)
         {
             case ButtonState.Buy:
                 SetButton(BuyButton);
                 break;
             case ButtonState.Equip:
                 SetButton(EquipButton);
                 break;


         }

          
         if(shop.isSold == true)
         {
             state = ButtonState.Equip;
             Debug.Log("working");
         }
         else if(shop.isSold == false)
         {
             state = ButtonState.Buy;
             Debug.Log(" buy working");
         }

     }

     void Update()
     {
     }
 
     void SetButton(GameObject button)
     {
         // Set on-click method of button
         Button myButton = GetComponent<Button>();
         Button targetButton = button.GetComponent<Button>();
 
         myButton.onClick = targetButton.onClick;
 
         // Set text of button
         TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI myText = GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>();
         TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI targetText = button.GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>();
 
         myText.text = targetText.text;
     }

      /*public static void SetEquipButton()
     {
      
     }

     public static void SetBuyButton()
     {
         
     }*/
 }
```

In the script the switch statement works like this if the enum ButtonState is ButtonState.Buy then it actives buy button else it active and sets Equip button. But the problem is I don't know how to change the ButtonScript State through script. So the switch statement doesn't have anything to change and save BuyButton to EquipButton. I had already tried this `/*I made this variable of type ButtonState*/ public ButtonState state` and then I did this to change the enum State  `state = ButtonState.Equip;` but it is not changing the State of the enum. I can see that in the inspector and there are not errors as well. So what should I do?
This is the script where I am calling to change the enum state:
the script is too long so this is the method where I am calling it and I also as told I already made a variable of type `public ButtonState state;`

```
 public class shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    
      public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
      public GameObject Item1;
      public GameObject Item2;
      public GameObject Item3;
      public GameObject Item4;
      public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI notenough;
      public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI notenough1;
      public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI notenough2;
      public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI notenough3;
      public GameObject buyButton;
      public GameObject buyButton1;
      public GameObject buyButton2;
      public GameObject buyButton3;
      public GameObject equipButton;
      public GameObject equipButton1;
      public GameObject equipButton2;
      public GameObject equipButton3;
      public float sec = 14f;
      public static bool isSold = false;
      public static bool isSold1 = false;
      public static bool isSold2 = false;
      public static bool isSold3 = false;
      public ButtonState state;
      public ButtonState1 state1;
      public ButtonState2 state2;
      public ButtonState3 state3;
 
      private Dictionary<GameObject, float> ItemPrices;
  
  
    void Start ()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score : " + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore")).ToString();
  
      ItemPrices = new Dictionary<GameObject, float>()
      {
       { Item1, 50f },
       { Item2, 80f },
       {Item3, 3500f},
       { Item4, 5000f },
       };
       notenough.enabled = false;
       notenough1.enabled = false;
       notenough2.enabled = false;
       notenough3.enabled = false;
       
    }
  
    public void PurchaseItem(GameObject Item)
   {
       foreach(KeyValuePair<GameObject, float> item in ItemPrices)
       {
            if (item.Key == Item)
            {
              
             float price = item.Value;
             float val = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore"); 
             if(val >= price)
             {
             val -= item.Value;
              PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Highscore", val);
              scoreText.text = "Score : " + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore")).ToString();
                  buyButton.SetActive(false);
                  equipButton.SetActive(true);
                  isSold = true;
                  state = ButtonState.Equip;
                 // Take away the cost of the item from the player's currency
                 //PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Highscore") -= item.Value;
             }
             else
             {
                 Debug.Log("not enough money");
                  notenough.enabled = true;
                  notenough1.enabled = true;
                  notenough2.enabled = true;
                  notenough3.enabled = true;
                 Invoke("noen", 2);
                 state = ButtonState.Buy;
             }
            }     
       }
   }

    public void noen()
  {
    notenough.enabled = false;
    notenough1.enabled = false;
    notenough2.enabled = false;
    notenough3.enabled = false;
   
  }

}
```

If any thing is unclear let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: Unclear where exactly you tried to put your call put if you do `state = ButtonState.XY;` <- This **is** how you change an enum via script in `c#` .. so you either do it wrong ^^ or you might want to change the title of your question since currently it is quite basic

Comment: I have edited the question added where I am calling the enum to change State. Pls review it.

Comment: In which class is that `PurchaseItem` method?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I edited the question and added a smaller version of the code, I think  it has all the question related code. Pls check that.

Comment: So yeah as said you are changing the `shop.state` field but do not pass this on to the according `LoadEveryThing.state` .. these two fields are completely unrelated so when you save/load you always keep the value of `LoadEveryThing.state`

Comment: so what should I write in my code and in which script?

Comment: In your `shop` instead of having local fields for `ButtonState` rather directly read and write into the `LoadEgeryThing` instance so it is saved and load correctly

Comment: Your condition `shop.isSold = true` is an assignment and rather should be `if(shop.isSold == true)` or actually simply put `if(shop.isSold)`

Comment: I worked on the script and it should work but it is still not changing the state in the inspector I have edited the shop script and LoadEveryThing script. Pls check that above in the question.

Comment: @derHugo I think maybe the problem is in the if statement if it is not why is it not changing the enum state?

Comment: so instead of just replying and answering a question you like to ignore it I posted that question because you weren't helping at least explain what you have said to do. Let's talk about the if statements I got no errors there but it isn't working you didn't even replied that. Now you will say I am doing this as a community helper but you are just letting other devs suffer.